# Check for '+' at the beginning of a string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check for an optional `+` sign at the beginning of a string followed by numbers. My regex works on regex101.com, but once I put it into my code it no longer works. The numbers are included in the resulting string, but the `+` isn't.

My code (React Native):

```
const [mobileNumber, setMobileNumber] = useState('');

const onChange = (strippedValue) => {
  const formattedValue = strippedValue.match(/[+][0-9]+/g);
    if (formattedValue?.length) {
      setMobileNumber(formattedValue[0]);
    } else {
      setMobileNumber('');
    }
};
<View>
  <TextInput value={mobileNumber} onChange={onChange}/>
</View>

// Expected returns

// strippedValue = "0422119966"
console.log(formattedValue) === ["0422119966"]

// strippedValue = "+0422119966"
console.log(formattedValue) === ["+0422119966"]

// strippedValue = "sjdb0422119966"
console.log(formattedValue) === ["0422119966"]

// strippedValue = "sjdb+0422119966"
console.log(formattedValue) === ["+0422119966"]

// Current returns

// strippedValue = "0422119966"
console.log(formattedValue) === ["0422119966"]

// strippedValue = "+0422119966"
console.log(formattedValue) === ["0422119966"]

// strippedValue = "sjdb0422119966"
console.log(formattedValue) === ["0422119966"]

// strippedValue = "sjdb+0422119966"
console.log(formattedValue) === ["0422119966"]
```

Comment: Can we see your actual code? It looks like your RegEx is fine.

Comment: your code does almost what you think .... formattedValue is an Array though

Comment: "it no longer works" ... what is the result, how is it different from the expected result ... the way you've written the question it's hard to say if that's what you actually are getting, or if that's what you want to get - note again: the result of your match will be an ARRAY not a string a you may be expecting

Comment: @JaromandaX I have edited my question to make it more clear

Comment: you're wrong about the current returns - your current returns are as expected

Comment: @JaromandaX if I was wrong about the current returns I wouldnt be here looking for answers. When I input into the TextInput the `+` is removed

Comment: what can I say ... `'sjdb+0422119966'.match(/[+]?[0-9]+/g)` outputs `["+0422119966"]` exactly like you expect (I note the code is missing the `?` now which would cause `'sjdb0422119966'.match(/[+][0-9]+/g)` to be `null`

Answer (score 0):

In your current regex the + character is not optional, but mandatory. What you actually meant to write was probably something more like `[+]?[0-9]+` (with a ? to indicate that it's optional). I personally would write it as `/\+?\d+/`